# R's equivalent to Stata's codebook command?

Tags: r, variables, stata

Is there an equivalent to Stata's codebook command or any other quick function to access the different possible values and codes of a variable?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R has the codebook `package` which is very similar to the Stata command `codebook`.

```
install.packages("codebook")
library(codebook)
new_codebook_rmd()
```